# Yii2 many to many relation. How to select with condition?

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

There are two models:

`Dish` and `Ingredient`.

They have relation many to many.I need to get Dishes where `ingredient_id` = `1,2,3`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the relevant code that is involved with the problem listed and view and controller action should be added to get the exact response.

The most basic way you can get the dishes having the ingredients `[1,2,3]` is using the `Model`

```
Dishes::find()->where(['IN','ingredient_id',[1,2,3]])->all();
```

The relations cannot be used in the current requirement they are used to get related records for one model inside another for instance if i have to get all the ingredient of a Dish with the id `1` and I have a relation defined with the `Ingredient` Model with the name `getIngredients()` i would do

```
$model=Dishes::findOne(1);
$ingredients=$model->ingredients;
```